# Script returns a System.IO.DirectoryInfo data instead of the string when it should explicitly return the string

Tags: powershell

I have the following script; which option 1 and 2 work correctly, but option 3, in which the user is expected to enter the directory name, does not work...

**This is my script:**

```
function Set-Destination {
    param (
        [string]$dockroot
    )
    $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/project/$dockroot"
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory
    }
}

function Get-DirectoryRoot {
    Write-Host "`n Set your DocumentRoot directory."  -ForegroundColor "Red"
    Write-Host " You have requested the configuration of custom URLs:"
    Write-Host "`n => 1. Base to (/)        Like: Apache, CodeIgniter"
    Write-Host " => 2. Base to (/public)  Like: Laravel, Symfony"
    Write-Host " => 3. Set your Custom    Like: Yii (web), CakePHP (webroot)"
    $choice = Read-Host " Choose option 1, 2, 3 (Press any key for default: 1)"
    if ($choice -eq "2") {
        $sourcePath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/docker/tpl/public"
        $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/project"
        Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $destinationPath -Recurse
        return "/public"
    } elseif($choice -eq "3") {
        Get-AddCyanLine
        Write-Host "`n Set your Custom Name Folder."  -ForegroundColor "Red"
        Write-Host " Note: if it not exists, it would be created."
        Write-Host " ==>" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor "Red"
        $dockroot = Read-Host
        Set-Destination -dockroot $dockroot
        return "/$dockroot"
    } else {
        $sourceFile = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/docker/tpl/public/index.php"
        $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath "/project"
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $destinationPath
        return "/"
    }
}

$dockroot = Get-DirectoryRoot

Write-Host "Retorno: $dockroot"

Pause
```

The objective is to return the string given by the user, instead it returns a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object and when I print it I get this in text format:

```
C:\Users\dfgsdgdf\OneDrive\Documents\DockerStack\project\app /app
```

when only the text you enter is expected: `/app`

I have tried eliminating `Set-Destination`, which apparently is what interferes and then it works, but I don't know what function it is interfering with and why it alters the value of $dockroot.

The code that damages the value of `$dockroot` is this part:

```
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $destinationPath -ItemType Directory
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it but I have a good idea as to what is going on. To answer on what you should do for the immediate fix, discard the output of `New-Item` 'cause that's what producing that, but if it's needed, have it write directly to the *information* stream. So, either `$null = New-Item ...`, `New-Item ... | Out-Null` or `Write-Host (New-Item ...)`. As for why it's happening, this is due to [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.tostring?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) being *implicitly* called when placed inside your `".."`. (1)

Comment: ok, the workaround that you suggest works, but I'm almost sure that this is an unwanted or unexpected result ... the fact of having to discard the output of New-Item because otherwise it would alter variables... it doesn't have sense ...

Comment: [In PowerShell, values can be returned even if the `return` keyword is not used. The results of each statement are returned.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return) (unless it is assigned to a variable)., this is also the case for the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) command (which does exit the function). The sense is in how the PowerShell [Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) is designed to work.

Comment: Thanks guys, so someone adds an answer to resolve the question?

Comment: i have published the project here: https://github.com/arcanisgk/Docker-Stack-Lamp